# Java: Date changes after parsing and applying new pattern

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat

I'm trying to convert a user-legible time String to an SQL-compatible String. Therefore I use the following code:

```
// User Date
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.YYYY - HH:mm:ss");
    String dateTimeUI = sdf.format(new Date());
    System.out.println("UI: " + dateTimeUI);
    labelDatumZeit.setText(dateTimeUI);
    System.out.println("[UI]: " + dateTimeUI);

// SQL-Date
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.YYYY - HH:mm:ss");
    Date d = sdf2.parse(dateTimeUI);
    sdf2.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    dateTimeSQL = sdf2.format(d);
    System.out.println("[SQL]: " + dateTimeSQL);
```

After converting to the new format my Data always is 2012-12-31 (+ correct time). Why is that?

Comment: What is the input, what is the output you get, and what is the output you expect?

Comment: My input = new Date() (e.g. 16.07.2013 13:00:56) <-- This is the correct output (for the UI). Then, after conversion, *dateTimeSQL* stores the wrong date --> (e.g. 2012-12-31 13:00:56). The time is always correct, but the date is always set to 2012-12-31. I would expect it to be 2013-07-16 13:00:56.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`YYYY` is the week year. `yyyy` is the year. If you expect both to be the same thing, then that's where the problem is.

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year):

> A week year is in sync with a WEEK_OF_YEAR cycle. All weeks between the first and last weeks (inclusive) have the same week year value. Therefore, the first and last days of a week year may have different calendar year values.
>
> For example, January 1, 1998 is a Thursday. If getFirstDayOfWeek() is MONDAY and getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() is 4 (ISO 8601 standard compatible setting), then week 1 of 1998 starts on December 29, 1997, and ends on January 4, 1998. The week year is 1998 for the last three days of calendar year 1997. If, however, getFirstDayOfWeek() is SUNDAY, then week 1 of 1998 starts on January 4, 1998, and ends on January 10, 1998; the first three days of 1998 then are part of week 53 of 1997 and their week year is 1997.

You want to use `yyyy` in both format.

Comment: YYYY means "week of year"

Comment: @jmrodrigg: no. It means "week year". week of year is `w`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that in second format you use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   Date date = new Date();
>   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.YYYY - HH:mm:ss");
>   String dateTimeUI = sdf.format(date);
>   System.out.println("UI: " + dateTimeUI);
>
>   // SQL-Date
>   Calendar calendar = sdf.getCalendar();
>   calendar.setTime(date);
>   System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
>
>   sdf.applyPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
>   String dateTimeSQL = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
>   System.out.println("[SQL]: " + dateTimeSQL);
> ```